# Populating a list view by button click - on the same page

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to populate a listview from the click of a button, which is contained on the same xml layout as the listview.

I wanted to have the button on the same page so I am trying to implement an onclicklistener for the button on the same xml. This button then runs the listview task I am trying to accomplish.

The task calls a PHP web service to read all data on my database and return it as a JSON array. What I want it to do is display below the button in a listview.

here is my Towns_php_activity.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="25"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListView
    android1:id="@android:id/list"
    android1:layout_width="match_parent"
    android1:layout_height="450dp"
    android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android1:id="@+id/buttonGo"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android1:text="GO!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my Town_php_Activity.java which uses the layout above:

```
package com.example.town;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Town_php_Activity extends Activity{


// url to make request
private static String url = "*************************";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_Data = "data";
private static final String TAG_ID = "_id";
private static final String TAG_Name = "Name";
private static final String TAG_Locale = "Locale2";
private static final String TAG_General = "General";


// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray data = new JSONArray();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.towns_php_activity);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    //setupActionBar();

        Button gettowns = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);
        gettowns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                GetTowns getTowns = new GetTowns();
            }
        });
}


public class GetTowns extends ListActivity{



       // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Data);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_Name);
            String locale = c.getString(TAG_Locale);
            String genre = c.getString(TAG_General);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_Name, name);
            map.put(TAG_Locale, locale);
            map.put(TAG_General, general);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_Name, TAG_Locale, TAG_General }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.locale, R.id.general });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String named = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String location = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.locale)).getText().toString();
            String gen = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.general)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_Name, named);
            in.putExtra(TAG_Locale, location);
            in.putExtra(TAG_General, gen);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}
}
}
}
```

what I am getting is errors on these parts:

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Multiple markers at this line

```
1.Syntax error on token "policy", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
2.Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

and

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Multiple markers at this line:

```
1.Return type for the method is missing
2.Syntax error on token "adapter", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
3.Syntax error on token ")", { expected after this token
4.adapter cannot be resolved to a type
```

Please can someone shed some light on why this for me as i have tried everything.

Thanks everyone for your time. Sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: I decided to answer this myself as I worked it out.

my layout was incorrect so the page would never load. I needed to have a linear layout inside a relative one so it would work.

I have now reverted back to removing the second class i create and running straight from the onClick command.

Now i need to add an autocomplete field and send of what is entered to a PHP to search, anyone have any good examples of autocompletetext fields?